# Hibernate "object references an unsaved transient instance" Problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I read a lot of document about my problem but suggestions couldn't solve my problem so i forced to open this topic.

My problem is that when i try to save my entity i am getting following error.
I added my entity classes. Thanks.

**Save code**

```
 @Transactional
@Override
public void saveEmployee(EmployeeTable employeeToSave)
{
    employeeDao.saveOrUpdate(employeeToSave);
}
```

**EmployeeTable**

```
package de.adesso.kkBonus.model;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import de.adesso.kkBonus.enums.*;
import de.adesso.kkBonus.util.BillConstants;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_table")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@ToString(of = "id")
public class EmployeeTable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "deleted")
private boolean deleted;

@Column(name = "name", length = 200, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(name = "tckn", length = 11)
private String tckn;

@Column(name = "social_security_number")
private String socialSecurityNumber;

@Column(name = "address", length = 1000)
private String address;

@Column(name = "birthday")
private Date birthday;

@Column(name = "lob")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private LobEnum lob;

@Column(name = "on_boarding_date", nullable = false)
private Date onBoardingDate;

@Column(name = "off_boarding_date")
private Date offBoardingDate;

@Column(name = "off_boarding_reason")
private String offBoardingReason;

@Column(name = "manager")
private boolean manager;

@Column(name = "created_by", length = 200, nullable = false)
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "creation_date")
private Date creationDate;

@Column(name = "modified_by", length = 200, nullable = false)
private String modifiedBy;

@Column(name = "modified_date", updatable = false)
private Date modifiedDate;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "manager_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
private EmployeeTable director;

@Column(name = "mail", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String mail;

@Column(name = "certificate", length = 1000)
private String certificate;

@Column(name = "billable")
private Boolean billable;

@Column(name = "outsource")
private Boolean outsource;

@Column(name = "location", length = 255)
private String location;

@Column(name = "gender")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private GenderEnum gender;

@Column(name = "blood_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private BloodTypeEnum bloodType;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "buddy", nullable = true)
private EmployeeTable buddy;

@Column(name = "contract_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ContractTypeEnum contractType;

@Column(name = "competence_center")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private CompetenceCenterEnum competenceCenter;

@Column(name = "position")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PositionEnum position;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "hrbp", referencedColumnName = "id")
private EmployeeTable hrbp;

@Column(name = "education_status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EducationStatusEnum educationStatus;

@Column(name = "military_status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MilitaryStatusEnum militaryStatus;

@Column(name = "military_exempt_reason", length = 500)
private String militaryExemptReason;

@Column(name = "military_postponement_date")
private Date militaryPostponementDate;

@Column(name = "personal_phone_number", length = 20)
private String personalPhoneNumber;

@Column(name = "work_phone_number", length = 20)
private String workPhoneNumber;

@Column(name = "private_email", length = 50)
private String privateEmail;

@Column(name = "emergency_person_name", length = 120)
private String emergencyPersonName;

@Column(name = "emergency_person_phone_number", length = 11)
private String emergencyPersonPhoneNumber;

//Sicil No
@Column(name = "registry_number", length = 50)
private String registryNumber;

@Column(name = "continuity", length = 3)
private Integer continuity;

@Column(name = "iban", length = 50)
private String iban;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "graduation_id")
private GraduationTable graduation;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employeeTable", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private UserTable userTable;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<InventoryTable> inventoryTables;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ResearchAndDevelopmentDetailsTable> researchAndDevelopmentDetailsTables;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employeeTable", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<EmployeeUploadTable> employeeUploadTables = Lists.newArrayList();

@Lob
@Column(name = "image", columnDefinition = "MEDIUMBLOB")
private String image;

@Transient
public boolean isMale() {
    return gender.equals(GenderEnum.MALE);
}

public EmployeeTable createCopy() {
    EmployeeTable target = new EmployeeTable();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, target);
    if (this.getGraduation() != null) {
        target.setGraduation(this.getGraduation().createCopy());
    }
    List listDocuments = new LinkedList();
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            listDocuments.add(employeeUploadTable.createCopy());
        }
        target.getEmployeeUploadTables().clear();
        target.getEmployeeUploadTables().addAll(listDocuments);
    }

    return target;
}

public boolean isOffBoarded() {
    return offBoardingDate != null;
}


public EmployeeUploadTable getResidenceCertificate() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.RESIDENCE_CERTIFICATE.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getBirthCertificate() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.BIRTH_CERTIFICATE.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getDiploma() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.DIPLOMA.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getMilitaryStatusCertificate() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.MILITARY_STATUS_CERTIFICATE.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getHealthReport() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.HEALTH_REPORT.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getWorkCertificate() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.WORK_CERTIFICATE.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getPayroll() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.PAYROLL.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable getCriminalRecord() {
    if (employeeUploadTables != null) {
        for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTables) {
            if (DocumentTypeEnum.CRIMINAL_RECORD.equals(employeeUploadTable.getContentType())) {
                return employeeUploadTable;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void addEmployeeUpdateTable(List<EmployeeUploadTable> employeeUploadTableList) {
    for (EmployeeUploadTable employeeUploadTable : employeeUploadTableList) {
        employeeUploadTable.setEmployeeTable(this);
        this.getEmployeeUploadTables().add(employeeUploadTable);
    }
}

public Boolean isAllDocumentsUploaded(){
    if(this.getBirthCertificate() == null || this.getResidenceCertificate() == null || this.getDiploma() == null
            || this.getMilitaryStatusCertificate() == null || this.getHealthReport() == null
            || this.getWorkCertificate() == null || this.getPayroll() == null || this.getCriminalRecord() == null){
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}

}
```

**EmployeeUploadTable**

```
 package de.adesso.kkBonus.model;

 import de.adesso.kkBonus.enums.DocumentTypeEnum;
 import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
 import lombok.Data;
 import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
 import lombok.ToString;
 import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
 import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_upload_table")
@ToString(of = "id")
public class EmployeeUploadTable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_fk")
private EmployeeTable employeeTable;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "content_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DocumentTypeEnum contentType;

@Column(name = "content")
private byte[] content;

@Transient
public EmployeeUploadTable createCopy() {
    EmployeeUploadTable target = new EmployeeUploadTable();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, target);
    return target;
}

public EmployeeUploadTable(DocumentTypeEnum documentTypeEnum) {
    this.setContentType(documentTypeEnum);
}
}
```

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object
>   references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance
>   before flushing: de.adesso.kkBonus.model.EmployeeTable; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references
>   an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before
>   flushing: de.adesso.kkBonus.model.EmployeeTable   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:681)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:563)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.saveEmployee(Unknown Source)  at
>   de.adesso.kkBonus.controller.impl.EmployeeControllerImpl.saveEmployee(EmployeeControllerImpl.java:219)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:737)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)   at
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:246)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:228)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   de.adesso.kkBonus.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at de.adesso.kkBonus.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   de.adesso.kkBonus.filter.AjaxExceptionFilter.doFilter(AjaxExceptionFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
>   de.adesso.kkBonus.model.EmployeeTable     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:294)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:537)
>     at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:311)
>     at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:321)
>     at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:294)     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4243)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:546)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:232)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:159)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
>     ... 61 more

Comment: Please add the code of saveOrUpdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is raised when mixing the `CascadeType.PERSIST` which works for the operation that persists an entity(JPA-proprietary), with the using saveOrUpdate.

there are Two Options:

### Option1:

adding the below CascadeType to the collection field:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
```

- CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE is used for save(), update(), and saveOrUpdate(), which are 3 Hibernate-proprietary methods. more on http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html

### Option2:

CascadeType.PERSIST is JPA-proprietary have an effect on persist().
More on: http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/CascadeType. In case of using JPA you should change your Dao to use persist instead of saveOrUpdate.

```
employeeDao.persist(employeeToSave);
```

- further reading: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-182

Answer (score 0):

It's so hard for debuging, I think you have to check 'graduation' object in EmployeeTable entity, Actually It's might be not null but it hasn't stored in database and it's not persist in hibernate, when you save EmployeeTable object it's throwing "object references an unsaved transient instance" exception